# Active menu class not working in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navigation, menubar

I am developing my own theme (using the functions of Twenty Fourteen (nothing has changed in functions.php)). My header does not contain wp_head() but I am using body_class() in my body tag. My menu is defined as so:

```
 <?php

  $menuParameters = array(
      'container'       => false,
      'echo'            => false,
      'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
      'depth'           => 0,

    );

   echo strip_tags(wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );

   ?>
```

Unfortunately, my current-menu-item is not being applied to my navigation anchors when on a wordpress-created page. Am I missing a function somewhere that renders this class? Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array(
  'container'=> '',
  'menu_class' => '',
  'menu_id' => '',
)); ?>
```